# How to set printf %d offset for Ghostscript?

Tags: printf, ghostscript

How would one go about specifying an offset for auto-naming the individual output files?  This would probably apply to other programs as well, but I need it to work for Ghostscript right now and can provide my example command for reference.

The following command outputs each individual page of a.pdf as an individual .png file (0.png, 1.png, 2.png, etc...)  What I would like to do is start with lets say 23.png, 24.png, 25.png, etc... Is there a way I can pass this via command line? Obviously (%d,23).png doesn't work, but perhaps there's another way to do this?

```
gswin32c -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -sOutputFile=%d.png a.pdf -c quit
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Looks like -dFirstPage does something similar for offsetting the start page of a multi-page input, but I can't seem to find anything like this for the output.

**FINAL EDIT:**
I'll leave this question open for anyone who may want to pitch in with a better idea, however this is what I ended up doing in Python.  (This method could probably be applied to any language that has access to the command line)

Output starts at 23.png and loops until a.pdf EOF

```
import os
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader

offset = 22
totalpages = PdfFileReader.getNumPages()

start = 1

while start <= totalpages:
    os.command('gswin32c -q \
                         -dNOPAUSE \
                         -dFirstPage=start \
                         -dLastPage=start \
                         -sDEVICE=tiffg4 \
                         -sOutputFile='+str(start+offset)+'.png \ 
                          a.pdf \
                         -c \
                          quit')
    start = start+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(BTW, you cannot use `-o %03d.png` to start the output file with `000.png` -- it will start with `001.png` as the first page....  Also, your `-sDEVICE=tiffg4` will output TIFF G4 files, not PNG files, regardless of what suffix you use for the output file....)

I can only think about an ugly workaround to achieve what you want. Since Ghostscript can process various input files and commandline sources in the same commandline, but still write the output in one go, you could pre-process a 22-page file file before the one you are interested in:

```
 gs \
   -o %03.tiff \
   -sDEVICE=tiffg4 \
    22page.pdf \
    the-real-pdf.pdf
```

Now simply delete the first 22 TIFF files, and the first page of your real PDF will be in `023.tiff`.

An alternative method would be to  do it like this:

```
 gs \
   -o %03.tiff \
   -sDEVICE=tiffg4 \
   -c "showpage showpage showpage showpage" \
   -c "showpage showpage showpage showpage" \
   -c "showpage showpage showpage showpage" \
   -c "showpage showpage showpage showpage" \
   -c "showpage showpage" \
   -f the-real-pdf.pdf
```

See the 22 `showpage` commands? It causes Ghostscript to process 22 empty pages of PostScript input, before the `-f the-real-pdf.pdf` file gets its turn. Or even better:

```
 gs \
   -o %03.tiff \
   -sDEVICE=tiffg4 \
   -c "$(for i in $(seq 1 22); do echo showpage; done)" \
   -f the-real-pdf
```

In order to create PNG files for the TIFFs, just use `-sDEVICE=pngalpha` (or `pngmono`, `png256` or `pnggray`)...

Comment: Thanks.  Getting the max page through PyPDF & specifying a range turns out to be much quicker, but +1 for the `-sDEVICE=pngalpha` . For some reason I thought this argument set the input decoder and you caught it for what it was...

Comment: @user1145643: I seriously doubt using a page range of 1 page only to "much quicker". If you need to process, say 30 pages, each of these individually, it means to call Ghostscript 30 times. given the overhead of Ghostscript's initialization and shutdown procedures, this surely is slower than calling ghostscript just once....

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Is processing empty pages practical for a PDF with a couple hundred or even potentially a 1000 pages? I'm trying to process in batches of 100 so it would basically skip the previous batches.